# How do I resolve a PublicKeyToken into a class? (Serialization issue)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization, assemblies

Hopefully I'm even asking my question correctly.  I'm getting the following exception while trying to serialize a specific object (I'm familar with the using the standard [Serializable] attribute)

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in
>   Assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

I cannot find where the heck this is coming from.  None of my classes inherit from Component, none of thier base classes inherit from component.

I've gotten to the point where I'm marking EVERY delegate\member varialbe as [NonSerialized], and its still throwing this exception every time I attempt to serialize.

So my question is: can I use this PublicKeyToken, and find what exact class\member is attempting to serialize?

Comment: Perhaps none of your types inherit from Component, but does one of them have a field with a type which inherits from Component? There must be _something_ referencing Component, otherwise this would point to a severe bug in your serializer! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a guess based on having seen this *too many times to count*: you have an `event`, and you have subscribed from that event to some UI code or something else `Component` related.

When using `BinaryFormatter`, events (or rather, the backing field) are serialized. If you don't want this, ensure your events are marked:

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
```

I'll also note that *so many* (IMO, subjective) bad things happen when using `BinaryFormatter` that I really would suggest using something else. XmlSerializer for example (mutters something inaudible about a quite-populate open-source binary formatter also being available).

Comment: You're a godsend.  This was half of the solution, it was a combination of this, and cloning the object before serialization, allowed the object to serialize.  I think it had something to do to the fact that the item was bound.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

No, PublicKey will not help you in finding the problem. PublicKeyToken is key that was used to sign the assembly and this key is used for more than one CLR assembly.

I would start trimming amount of objects to serialize till I the issue disappear. Also try to turn off "my code" (Tools -> Options -> Debugging) and start breaking on all exceptions - you **may** get slightly better idea where it fails first.

Comment: I'm going to try those few options, and then start trimming.

Its going to be incredibly time-comuming, its kind of the 'core' dataobject for our app, you gotta do what you gotta do though...